# How to abort publishing if there is any error in storage extension?

Tags: web8.5, si4t, elasticsearch

We are using SDL Web 8.5.

While publishing any item we are also pushing some content of the item in elastic search using si4t storage extension sometime there is an error between deployer and elastic search service we would like to abort publishing and shown to the user as failed in publishing queue if there is any error while pushing content to elastic search.

how we can handle this in our si4t extension jar file?

Comment: Have you tried to simply throw Exception?

Comment: I think SI4T already does this. See https://github.com/SI4T/SI4T/blob/develop/storage-extensions/src/main/java/com/tridion/storage/si4t/JPASearchDAOFactory.java#L199

Comment: @Raimond, I think you can post that as an answer :).

Answer (score 1):

Yes. As @Rai mentioned it's already handled in the SI4T refer to that link which rai mentioned in his comment.

In your custom elastic search deployer storage extention code, you can add one more exception catch for elastic search.

**Example:**

```
catch (ElasticsearchException e)
        {
            logException(e);
            throw new IndexingException("Elastic Search Client Exception:" + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Also, see this code - https://github.com/avmgan/SI4T-elasticsearch/blob/master/src/main/java/org/si4t/elastic/ElasticSearchIndexer.java#L140

I hope it helps.